# how to fix " facebook link probleme"

Tags: excel, facebook, converters

I'm having a problem  i have this kind of link :

link (01) http://www.facebook.com/_668280082122963   when you click on this url you get this link(02) :
https://web.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=pfbid0oTz2xcTsrveFJQoJNcRaPs6ssXYCsiDVDyLrjqFLBXywhCNCRNzmrHCptwbAVa1l&id=100089783507759&comment_id=668280082122963

i want to find a quick way to convert 1000 link(01)  to lin(02)

Please help me

I tried some codes in excel but without result

Because i have a large number of links, i am unable to do them manually